# Setting the charset with GeoTools in Java

Tags: shapefile, geojson, convert, geotools

I have a well-made geojson file. Of course it is well made with shapefiles. I want to set the charset when creating the shapefile.

Below is part of the code.

```
File outFile = new File("D:\\geojson.shp");
outFile.createNewFile();
FileDataStore ds = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(outFile);  
ds.createSchema(outSchema);   
SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = ds.getFeatureSource();
```

Where can I set the charset?

Answer (score 1):

[`ShapeFileDataStore`](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/data/shapefile/ShapefileDataStore.html) has a method [`setCharset(Charset)`](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/data/shapefile/ShapefileDataStore.html#setCharset-java.nio.charset.Charset-) that might just do what you want.